# calling different functions based on a string

Tags: function, coding-style, eval

I am not sure if it's even possible.
Say I have the following function defined:

```
a(), b(), c()
```

I want to get a user input from command line (either "a", "b", "c") and according to the input call the corresponding function

BUT without using cases or if's
ie:

```
input = getinput()
if exist?(input){
  input()
}
```

Does this exist in any language?

Comment: If you don't use any conditional checks, what's going to happen if an invalid or non-existent function name is passed through the command line? I can only think of your program blowing into smithereens.

Comment: comment +1 oh this was never really meant for development purposes, more out of curiosity if it can be done but you are definitely right. Also the pseudo exist? function would ideally verify if there is such a function (similar to respond_to? in ruby)

Comment: Well your code example with the if statement can be done in a number of languages like Ruby, Objective-C and PHP. But it's really there to validate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do something like that. For instance, in Python:

```
def a():
    return 'a'

def b():
    return 'b'

def select_func(name):
    return eval(name)()
```

Executing select_func('a') will return 'a', and executing select_func('c') will raise an exception